# Android Masking

Tags: android, graphics, android-view

I need to make a view(to act as mask over other view) [image: overlay] . The circle is transparent and outer region is translucent. 
I am able to make it using canvas.clipRegion(..) but http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html says it is unsupported in hardware accelerated devices. I am trying to make this view by Xfermode but still unsucessful.

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.drawArc()` method can help you.

Set the Paint style to `STROKE`,set `Alpha`(150,maybe)

and then ,set `STROKE WIDTH` to fill the screen.